# Компонент multiselect для react 16

Tags: reactjs

Использовал в проекте react-select. После обновления реакта на 16 версию, компонент перестал работать. Посоветуйте что можно использовать вместо него на реакт 16. Нужен именно мультиселект

Comment: а че с react-select? последнюю версию ставили (react-select@next ) ?

Answer (score 1):

[Antd](https://ant.design/components/select/) попробуй, есть не только мультиселект